# Wordpress plugin Manual Related Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed the Wordpress Plugin: Manual Related Posts (https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-manual-related-posts/)

After installing i'm trying to manually ad Related Posts to a page. 
But i can only select Posts or Pages.... Regarding the plugin it should also be possible to use the Media function but it won't show up.

I downgraded to Wordpress 3.9.2 which is the required version for this plugin (there's no support for newer wordpress versions)

Hope someone can help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to add manually related posts in your blog

```html
<div class="relatedposts">
    <h3>Related posts</h3>
    <?php
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
 
        if ($tags) {
            $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            $args=array(
                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
                'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
 
        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
 
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
 
        <div class="relatedthumb">
            <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br />
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
 
        <?php }
        }
        $post = $orig_post;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
```